# Azure MSAL Authentication and custom JWT Authentication in Blazor

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to add Azure MSAL Authentication to an existing Blazor WASM application that already handles authentication with JWT.
But if I register a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` I use, blazor throw at runtime:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Specified cast is not valid.
> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Looking through sources, It seems it throws because an MSAL class expects that IServiceProvider returns an `IRemoteAuthenticationService<TRemoteAuthenticationState>` as `AuthenticationStateProvider` see [WebAssemblyAuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions at line 65](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/WebAssemblyAuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

That's the `AuthenticationStateProvider` implementation I use:

```
public class ApiAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;

    public ApiAuthenticationStateProvider(AuthenticationHttpClient authHttpClient, ILocalStorageService localStorage)
    {
        _httpClient = authHttpClient.HttpClient;
        _localStorage = localStorage;
    }
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var savedToken = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken))
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(savedToken), "jwt")));
    }

    public void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string email)
    {
        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email) }, "apiauth"));
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }

    public void MarkUserAsLoggedOut()
    {
        var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        var payload = jwt.Split('.')[1];
        var jsonBytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
        var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);

        keyValuePairs.TryGetValue(ClaimTypes.Role, out object roles);

        if (roles != null)
        {
            if (roles.ToString().Trim().StartsWith("["))
            {
                var parsedRoles = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(roles.ToString());

                foreach (var parsedRole in parsedRoles)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, parsedRole));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roles.ToString()));
            }
            keyValuePairs.Remove(ClaimTypes.Role);
        }

        claims.AddRange(keyValuePairs.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString())));

        return claims;
    }

    private byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
    {
        switch (base64.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
            case 3: base64 += "="; break;
        }
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }
}
```

Which I register as follows: `builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();`

Is there a way to solve the issue ? I've looked at this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69309263/custom-authenticationstateprovider-breaking-azure-msal-authentication-in-blazor) but I'm not been able to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using  `AuthenticationStateProvider` one of the appropriate System.Security.Claims.AuthenticationTypes values must be added as a parameter along with claimsIdentity.

i.e;  To you blazor app you will have to add authenticationType parameter value with ClaimsIdentity so your code will be changed to:
like

```
var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Needs Auth Type Here"));
```

***example:***

> ```
> public class ApiAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
> {
>    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
>    {
>        ....
>                
>        var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "xyz@afs.com") };
>        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationTypes.Password));
>        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
>        ...
>
>        return Task.FromResult(authState);
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Note the  AuthenticationTypes.Password parameter in the above code for
> ClaimsIdentity. Check to change it in all places wherever
> ClaimsIdentity is constructed.

If needed check  the auth type of user

> ```
> if (User.Identity.AuthenticationType == AuthenticationTypes.Password) {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

So that you can be able to login successfully.

Or try using [RemoteAuthenticationService](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/Services/RemoteAuthenticationService.cs) as said in [https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30971#issuecomment-1261835057)

[image]

**Reference:** [.net core - Custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` Authentication Failing - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797954/custom-authenticationstateprovider-authentication-failing)

Comment: Many thanks for your effort.
I don't understand how changing the ClaimPrincipal could possibly solve the CastException I got, but I tried and indeed it don't work. 

However the github issue 30971 is exactly the problem I have, I'm marking that question as solved as the provided link explain the issue and give a workaround